# How do you locate the source of a program in the Applications tab in the Sound settings in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audio-jack, ardour

I was messing with some of the settings and audio software in Ubuntu 18.04 to try to make a plugin in `ardour` work. This involved downloading some plugins, and also installing and reinstalling multiple packages, including `pulseaudio`. Everything seems to work again, but I have this strange application in my audio settings that seems to make a chirp sound when an external drive is mounted or unmounted from the computer.

[image]

Anyone know what Lav57.83.100 is? If not, how would I go about identifying its source?